# How to add CocoaPods to an existing project that already links to frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Have an xcode project that builds fine. It links against several frameworks "manually installed" using Build Phases already. After following the guides and running pod install on the project directory it fails to build anymore, giving undefined symbols for {insert arch here} errors about one of the frameworks that links fine without cocoapods installed. This is without any actual pods in the Podfile, so it's more of a general CocoaPods issue than a specific pod issue.

pod install does give the warning's about HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS being overridden, but I already have the Configuration of the app project pointing to the cocoapods-created config file and that has ($inherited) already before the other settings. It's not an issue of seeing the library headers because the failure is a linker error, not a compiler one. Is Cocoapods just not a valid choice for an existing legacy iOS app project?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods should work with an existing app. I think it is the Header Search Path, which caused many troubles for me. You should add manually an Entry to your Framework.

Best solution: add your Frameworks with Cocoapods, if they're available. If not, you have to set the header search path correctly.

Comment: Search header path on which target, my app or the Pods target? Also, it's finding the headers just fine - it's a linker error, not a compiler error

Comment: On your apps target. I think you should describe your error more precious